# Css switch statement

Tags: css, vue.js, css-selectors

So, I currently have something like this in vue:

```html
  <div class="item" :class="{ priority: item.priority }">
```

What I want to do is to be able to change my border-color based on the item's priority, so if there's something like a switch statement in CSS that can enable me to achieve this?

Comment: create a computed property, assign it as a style or a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no switch statement in CSS, but you could do this in JavaScript, and use a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) to apply it to the `div`.

For instance, use a `getClass()` method based on priority:

```html
<template>
  <div class="item-list" v-for="item in items">
    <div class="item" :class="getClass(item.priority)">...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ⋮
  methods: {
    getClass(priority) {
      switch (priority) {
        case 1: return 'high-priority'
        case 2: return 'medium-priority'
        default: return 'low-priority'
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.high-priority {
  border-color: red;
}
.medium-priority {
  border-color: orange;
}
.low-priority {
  border-color: gray;
}
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-calculate-class-from-prop?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyList.vue)

Or for [improved rendering performance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods), [compute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) a new item list that includes a `class` property whose value is the result of `getClass()`:

```html
<template>                                   
  <div class="item-list" v-for="item in computedItems">
    <div class="item" :class="item.class">...</div>
  </div>                             
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ⋮
  computed: { 
    computedItems() {
      return this.items.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        class: this.getClass(item.priority),
      })) 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-calculate-class-from-prop-ygryso?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyList.vue)